# Error Projecting Raster (.hdf) Using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, coordinate-system, hdf

I want to project HDF files (MODIS images) to another coordinate system using ArcPy. The following is the code I wrote:

```
input_ras="N:\\mod16a2\\MOD16A2.A2001001.h24v05.006.2017068142418.hdf"

out_ras= "\test.tif"

# the coordinate system which is required
out_co="G:\\Rathore\\vic_auto7\\shape_proj.prj"

arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(in_raster=input_raster,out_raster=out_ras,out_coor_system=out_co)
```

This script produces the following error:

```
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-0d17576ef2fe> in <module>()
 arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(in_raster=input_ras,out_raster="out_ras,out_coor_system=out_co)

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py in ProjectRaster(in_raster, out_raster, out_coor_system, resampling_type, cell_size, geographic_transform, Registration_Point, in_coor_system)
   9700         return retval
   9701     except Exception as e:
-> 9702         raise e
   9703 
   9704 @gptooldoc('RegisterRaster_management', None)

ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
Undefined coordinate system for input dataset.
Failed to execute (ProjectRaster).
```

I checked the projection of input file and it is:

```
"PROJCS['Unknown_datum_based_upon_the_custom_spheroid_Sinusoidal',GEOGCS['GCS_Unknown_datum_based_upon_the_custom_spheroid',DATUM['D_Not_specified_based_on_custom_spheroid',SPHEROID['Custom_spheroid',6371007.181,0.0]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Sinusoidal'],PARAMETER['false_easting',0.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',0.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]")
```

Comment: Are you running your code from IDLE or from somewhere else?

Comment: Does your code work if you copy `N:\\mod16a2\\MOD16A2.A2001001.h24v05.006.2017068142418.hdf` to be `C:\\temp\\test.hdf` and use that path instead of the one with multiple dots in it?

Answer (score 2):

The way to resolve this is to put in the full projection of the coordinate system for input dataset as an argument to `ProjectRaster_management`:

```
arcpy.ProjectRaster_management (ifpn, ofpn, "4326", "NEAREST", "#", "#", "#", "PROJCS['Unknown_datum_based_upon_the_custom_spheroid_Sinusoidal',GEOGCS['GCS_Unknown_datum_based_upon_the_custom_spheroid',DATUM['D_Not_specified_based_on_custom_spheroid',SPHEROID['Custom_spheroid',6371007.181,0.0]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Sinusoidal'],PARAMETER['false_easting',0.0],PARAMETER['false_northing',0.0],PARAMETER['central_meridian',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]")
```

`ifpn` and `ofpn` are my input and output rasters respectively. If these are already assigned your variables (as you did with `input_ras` and `out_ras`), you don't need to reassign them within the function.